# I installed Debian 12 and tried installing packages and this popped up

Tags: linux

[image: Error image]

Help Debian 12 spits this error
About

> "/sda/sr0 can't open blockdev"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you told Debian you want to install software from DVD and now it asks you to insert the disk. You probably installed Debian from a full DVD image and at the end of the install it asked you if you want to use that media for future updates/installations and you said yes to that. So check your installation sources and remove the DVD media.

Comment: Thanks it worked.